# Aframe Ray caster Intersection

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

After Switching to Master build of Aframe The raycaster intersection event seems to become null although i kept the exact same code :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@efcc8a0a919811fe5bd4ab6fd60bfbb8e85a98a1/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
```

with the Registered Component :

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
  dependencies: ['raycaster'],
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function (evt) {
      console.log(evt.detail.intersection);//this returns null
      var intersection=evt.detail.intersection.point;
      startTimer(intersection.x,intersection.y,intersection.z);
    });
  }
});
```

and the camera where i put the collider-check

```
<a-entity id="cameraParent"  position="0 0 0" >
        <a-entity id="cam" camera="zoom:1;"  look-controls collider-check position="0 0 0" >
          <a-entity cursor=" rayOrigin: mouse"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0; radiusOuter: 0"
            material="color: black; shader: flat"></a-entity>

          <a-entity raycaster="showLine:true; far: 1000" line="color:orange; opacity:1" ></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
```

My a-sky where i want to catch intersections

```
 <a-sky  class="collidable" id="image-360" radius="200"  src="#{{$tour_images[0][0]->name}}" data-image-id="{{$tour_images[0][0]->id}}"></a-sky>
```

Comment: Why are you using the class attribute  on the sky element? If you want to whitelist the ray traced entities, you need to add the objects property in the raycaster component. Right now you are testing against all the entities in the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now have to grab the intersection data manually, it was to prevent memory garbage in the event details.

The event detail provides a convenient references to the method to grab the intersection.

`evt.detail.getIntersection(this.el);`

Also the `raycaster-intersected` event is no longer spammed. It is only called once on intersection start. If you need to spam it, listen for the event, store a variable, and use `tick`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is still returning null

Comment: Also your cursor won't work if it and the raycaster are separate entities. They should be the same entity. The collider-check seem like it should go on the sky since it's the `intersected` event. The `intersection` event is what is listened to on the raycaster. So either move the collider-check to sky, or adapt the collider-check to use `raycaster-intersection` and attach to raycaster

Also the `raycaster-intersected` event is no longer spammed. It is only called once on intersection start. If you need to spam it, listen for the event, store a variable, and use tick.

Comment: I am  doing this version change due to a problem i faced when i updated chrome and the a-sky went crazy rotating Also the buttons are not workiing on some IOS versions. Is there a soltion i can add in the code besides updating the version of Aframe am using from 0.8.0 to 0.8.2 ?