# AFRAME raytrace get reference of intersected entity

Tags: javascript, aframe

I got a raycaster component attached to the vr controller entity:

```
 <a-entity id="righthand" 
          vive-controls="hand: right; " 
          oculus-touch-controls="hand: right;"
          controls-ui
          collider-check
       >
        <a-entity raycaster="objects: .collidable; showLine: true; far: 100; " line="color: blue; opacity: 0.5" ></a-entity>

</a-entity>
```

and I got an entity in the scene that will receive the raytrace events:

```
<a-entity id='myCube' class="collidable" position="0 1.25 -6"  obj-model="obj: #cube-obj; mtl: #cube-mtl" >
       </a-entity>
```

How do I get the id or any reference of the collided entity in the 'raycaster-intersected' event?
I tried the following code, and nothing seems to contains this data:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
  dependencies: ['raycaster'],

  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function (evt) {

      console.log(evt.detail.el);  // not here

      console.log(evt.detail.intersection); // not here

      console.log(evt.detail);// not here

      console.log('Player hit something!');
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

---------Update-----------

@Piotr Adam Milewski  answer is correct. The event to be listening is **raycaster-intersection** instead of **raycaster-intersected**. In that way you can loop an array of the intersected entities.

Is it possible to get the same result from **raycaster-intersected** ??  If that event is emitted on the intersected entity, then It should be possible to get its id and other properties.I dont think is ideal to loop over an array every time an intersection event occurs.

Comment: i've added a solution using the event on the target

Comment: Yeah, now it works. Maybe Aframe documentation should mention all this.

Comment: Your collider-check should be attached to the raycaster. The code above now has two raycasdters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/raycaster.html#events):

- `raycaster-intersected` is emitted on the intersected entity. It contains info about the raycasting entity and the intersection details.
- `raycaster-intersection` is emitted on the raycasting entity, and contains a list of intersected entities.

When using `raycaster-intersection` try accessing `evt.detail.els` for an array of intersected entities. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn4mLce3/1/)

---

Since the `raycaster-intersected` is emitted on the intersected entity, you can detect whether the raycaster touched your target.

```
target.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', (e)=> { 
  // intersected, e.target contains the element
  // e.detail.getIntersection(e.target) contains info about the intersection
})
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn4mLce3/9/). Fiddle with `getIntersection()` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn4mLce3/11/).

Comment: I'm getting this error: e.detail.getIntersection is not a function. I tried evt.detail.el.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.el) but is null. If it helps  I am using https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js.

Comment: ngoKevin mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53411935/2425787), it seems to be implemented on the master branch but i'm also getting nulls out of it, so i've updated the anwser (+fiddle).

Comment: Shouldn't the code say `raycaster-intersected`? `getIntersection` need to pass in the intersected entity, not raycaster entity.

Comment: @ngokevin thanks it was a typo, i'm not sure why it didn't work earlier, but i've updated my anwser with `getIntersection ` and a fiddle.